# How to prove to friend I have solution to puzzle (without revealing it)?

Tags: cryptography

My friend Paul set me this arithmetic puzzle:

> To make 21 from the numbers 1, 5, 6, 7. You can use the operations add, subtract, multiply, divide as well as brackets. You must use each number once.

After I solved it myself, I set the puzzle to another friend Ollie. He thinks it's impossible. How can I prove otherwise to Ollie—without revealing the solution? Can it be done without a trusted third party?

Also, how should I show my solution to Paul? I suspect he might not have one himself. If that's the case, I'd rather not tell mine—or at least expose him in the process.

Comment: this isn't an Info Sec question, per se.

Comment: You are asking to provide 0-knowledge proof of a disconnected fact. At best, you could archive your solution with a timestamp and then prove that you had a solution at that time. I'm not sure that you can 'prove' that you have a solution without revealing it. You could also reveal a portion of your solution, for instance the number of operators, the number of characters, etc. as a checksum to be used as a comparison after you reveal your solution later.

Comment: Not quite the answer, but a bit related: you could create a hash of your solution and share that. With this you could then prove afterwards, when you reveal the solution that you already had it some time in past (when you revealed that hash).

Comment: Hmm sorry, I've rewrite @domen **right** answer. (Yes I think it is THE answer. domen, if you post your own, I will drop mine).

Comment: So... Is it 6 / (1 - 5/7)?

Comment: You may be interested by *Applied Cryptography*, by Bruce Schneier. It deals with many problems similar to this one (although not, as far as I can recall, this exact problem).

Comment: In math, simplifying the formula would result in 21. This puzzle requires intentionally complicating 21 to a formula. This is why the cylons will rule us all one day.

Comment: I believe this is applicable to security / cryptography, but would also be a good fit for: puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [zero-knowledge proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) to demonstrate that you have a solution to a general class of problem. (For example: "I can efficiently find the prime factorization of any number. I won't tell you how I do it, but I'll prove my ability by quickly factorizing any number you throw at me.") However, here, the solution is *how* you solved the problem; it's tautological to say you can't show how you solved the problem without giving away how you solved the problem.

You could secretly but provably declare your solution via [cryptographic commitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme). For example, you publish a hash of your solution and then later publish your solution. That allows you to prove that you had the solution for at least as long as the hash has been public. However, it only becomes clear that the secret you committed is a valid solution after you make the secret public. (This approach will allow Paul to compare his (non-)answer with yours -- simply compare hashes, using a standard format -- but it will not prove anything to Ollie.)

For Ollie, you need some way of demonstrating a solution to a different problem that maps onto the actual problem in some provable way. I briefly considered some kind of [fully homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption), but I don't see how you could homomorphically demonstrate the problem in a way that 1) doesn't allow your friend to decrypt it and 2) still allows your friend to verify the result. For example, consider an attempt at an iterative zero-knowledge proof with a homomorphic scheme that can encrypt (`Enc`) with a public key and decrypt (`Dec`) with a private key:

1. Show your friend `Enc(1)`, `Enc(5)`, `Enc(6)`, and `Enc(7)` in a random order, and separately show `Enc(21)`. At this point, your friend may stop these steps, demand the private key and verify that you are not lying about the values of the numbers. (This prevents you from using the wrong values, since you'd probably get caught if you played enough times.)
2. Perform the necessary mathematical operations on the first four encrypted values to produce 21. (This step gives away the necessary operations, which is suboptimal, but it does not reveal which values go with which operations.) At this point we can no longer give your friend the decryption key, or else he will be able to view the entire solution.
3. Perform a homomorphic equality test of the result from step 2 against the `Enc(21)` from step 1. This produces an encrypted boolean.

There is no way to allow your friend to decrypt the boolean without also allowing him to decrypt every other value, which would reveal your solution entirely. Therefore, there is no way to verify to your friend the correctness of your solution.

Comment: Also, if you and Paul separately send the same hashed solution to Ollie, it's an indicator that it exists. It's not proof, obviously, since you and Paul can agree to hash something else, but it's still some assurance.

Answer (score 4):

There are only 7680 possible expressions using exactly once each of the four values, and binary operators in a list of four possible binary operators. A number of these expressions are in fact duplicates of each other, since two of the operators (addition and multiplication) are commutative. You can tell Ollie and Paul that they are lazy bastards.

This short number of candidates invalidates most cryptographic endeavours, since a zero-knowledge proof is always relative to a core hard problem: a ZK proof is a proof where you demonstrate that you know a solution without giving to the verifier any information *that he could not obtain by himself*. Here, trying out all possible solutions is simply too easy, so Ollie and Paul can already gain by themselves all the information that is to be obtained.

(Besides, according to my own computations, there is no solution. Hence, the solution to the puzzle must be some sort of pun or loophole, which by nature evades mathematical analysis.)

**Edit:** there was a bug in my program (damned silent conversion `double` to `int`; no warning from GCC even with `-W -Wall`). Indeed there is one solution, the one found by @Gudradain (and it is unique). For those interested in such things, here is [my horrible program](http://pastebin.com/VSb0zk5H).

Comment: 7680? Somehow I end up to 9216 using each number once and the operator any number of times...

Comment: If we use each number once then there are only three applied operators. There are 5 possible structures for a binary tree with four leaves; each structure then has 64 possibilities for the operators (4 choices for each non-leaf node) and there are 24 (factorial of 4) possible values for the 4 leaves. 5\*64\*24 = 7680.

Comment: Oh! (9216 / 6) * 5 = 7680. I was building all possibilities using prefix notation and going at the problem recursively. G(4) = 4 * (4*3) * G(3), G(3) = 4 * (3*2) * G(2), G(2) = 4 * (2*1)

Comment: Regarding there being no solution, @Gudradain figured it out: 6 / (1 - 5/7)

Comment: There was a bug in my program. I now find that solution (and it is unique).

Answer (score 2):

One workaround I could think of would be writing an open source website. The site is configured to accept one type of formula, e.g. one that contains one or more of `()/*+=` (in any amount and any order) and `1`, `5`, `6` and `7` must occur only once. The input formula will be stored in a file or database, the formula evaluated, and the result shown. Then the friend can see that you have a solution which really results in 21.

Then there is the problem of hosting the website. If you host it, you could modify the code. If your friend hosts it, he could peek at the stored formula. He would however be certain that you are not pranking him. It's hardly advantageous over simply telling him there really, really is a solution, but now he can be 100% sure. Only now you have to trust him with not peeking at the solution.

I'm not sure if there are any better solutions, this is the best I can come up with.

I think this is besides the question, but for completeness: if you want to check whether you have the same answer without revealing the answer to each other, you can use a hash function. If you run sha-256 over both of your answers, the resulting hash should be identical. Be sure to use the same format though (spacing, order of things, etc.), perhaps you can give a few hashes to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You could share the hash of the answer.

1. store the answer in a static file. `cat >answer.txt`
2. hash this file `sha1sum answer.txt`.
3. share the resulting hash with your friend.

Once puzzle timeout reached, you could show your file and
re compute the hash. They must match!